# ¿Como comparar una huella de una base de datos y otra ingresada usando digital persona y c# con sql server?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, biometrico

Aquí vengo con este caso y es que busco comparar una huella ingresada en el formulario de mi proyecto y que al ser ingresada ejecute una secuencia para que la compare con las que están en la base de datos y al hacerlo me diga si existe o no, en caso de existir cambiara el texto de una de mis label con la ID de esa huella. El problema es que a pesar de ingresar la huella incorrecta el sistema me avisa que si existe y encima no cambia el texto de mi label mandándome un error de lectura en los datos...

Espero y puedan ayudarme aqui les dejo el codigo que estoy usando para la comparación y el lector de huella que uso es un Digital Persona 4500.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
    con.Open();
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT COUNT(*) from Prueba where CONVERT(varchar(40), HUELLA) like '%@Huella%'", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Huella", SqlDbType.VarBinary);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        cmd.Parameters["@Huella"].Value = ms.GetBuffer();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Ya existe");
            Resultado.Text = reader["ID"].ToString();
            con.Close();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Existe");


        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error en:" + ex.ToString());
        Controlalodor.Text = "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que la consulta que haces es un `SELECT COUNT(*)`, para ver si existe alguna huella, pero posteriormente en lugar de comprobar el resultado, compruebas `reader.HasRows`.

El `SELECT COUNT(*)` siempre te va a devolver una fila, con la suma de los registros que cumplen la condición, con lo que `reader.HasRows` siempre te va a devolver `true`. Lo que debes comprobar si el resultado de la consulta es 0:

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{    
     reader.Read();
     if (reader.GetInt32(0) == 0)
     {
          MessageBox.Show("No Existe");
     }
     else
     {
          MessageBox.Show("Ya existe");
          Resultado.Text = reader["ID"].ToString();
          con.Close();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Estimado. Ajuste el if tal como lo tienes aun asi solo me manda los "No Existe" comparandola con las huellas que ingrese en la base de datos

Comment: @Kirito eso ya es diferente, es posible que la consulta sql que estas usando no sea la correcta. No tengo conocimientos de Digital persona para poder ayudarte con eso, te recomendaría lo primero intentar hacer la consulta desde sql server para probar la consulta y ver cuando te devuelve las huellas ya registradas.

Comment: Sale muchas gracias por tu apoyo me pondré a investigar mas